# Running Silverlight unit tests in TFS 2010 build

Tags: silverlight, unit-testing

We have some Silverlight unit tests running successfully in VS 2010.
I am using the Silverlight unit test framework (http://silverlight.codeplex.com).

For Example:

```
/// <summary>
/// test the loading of the big org strucutre from the server
/// this operation has a timeout attached.
/// </summary>
[TestMethod]
[Asynchronous]
[TimeoutAttribute(60100)]
public void LoadOrgStructure()
{
    _loadOrgStructureStart = getCurrentTicks();
    OrgStructureMemberDAC.Instance.GetOrganisationStructure(new EventHandler<GetOrganisationStructureOrgStructureMemberVOCompletedEventArgs>(delegate(object s, GetOrganisationStructureOrgStructureMemberVOCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //only run the following code in time
        if (getElapsedMilliseconds(_loadOrgStructureStart) <= 60000)
        {
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                //Clientside error
                throw e.Error;
            }
            else if (e.Result.Error != null)
            {
                //Serverside error
                throw new AssertFailedException(e.Result.Error.Message);
            }
            else
            {
                Assert.IsNotNull(e.Result.Result); // there must be root elements                        
                Assert.IsTrue(e.Result.Result.Count > 0); 
                Assert.IsNotNull(e.Result.Result[0].ChildMemberLstObj); //there must be childs
                Assert.IsTrue(e.Result.Result[0].ChildMemberLstObj.Count > 0); 
                EnqueueTestComplete();
            }
        }
    }));
}
```

When I run this test in VS 2010, a browser window is openend and the test is running successfully.
Now I want to run such asynchronous tests with my TFS-2010-Build. But I don´t know how I can start this test with the build. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible. Take a look at the following solution : [How to run Silverlight automated tests on TFS build server?](http://pyxis-tech.com/blog/2011/01/24/how-to-run-silverlight-automated-tests-on-tfs-build-server/)

It explain how to combine StatLight(an open source tool used to run Silverlight tests)  and a TFS 2010 custom activity to run Silverlight test on continuous integration and notify you when a test fail.

Answer (score 0):

I have found various solutions [using generic test wrappers](http://www.nielshebling.de/?p=167) or [modifying the workflow to use StatLight](http://pyxis-tech.com/blog/2011/01/24/how-to-run-silverlight-automated-tests-on-tfs-build-server/), but it all feels like one big hack. I haven't seen any official guidance from the product group either on this which leads me to believe they haven't figured it out.